# How to create an IIS7 Virtual Directory Under Another Website (Not the Default Website) Using WiX

Tags: iis, wix, virtual-directory

I am really struggling to create a Virtual Directory in an existing website in IIS7 using WiX.

To illustrate, what I therefore have are:

1) The IIS Default Website, and 
2) Another website which is a container for a number of business applications and we can call "ContainerWebsite".

What I therefore desperately wish to do is create the following using WiX:

a) Create a virtual directory for one of the business applications (let's call it "BusinessApp1") under "ContainerWebsite". The final structure in IIS will therefore look like this "ContainerWebiste\BusinessApp1"

Should the above virtual directory be successful, I intend to create similar virtual directories for the remaining business applications.

b) Create a dedicated IIS Application Pool for each of the business applications installed to the "ContainerWebsite".

I would be extremely grateful for any assistance towards achieving thie.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Any errors you've faced with?

Answer (score 0):

See http://blog.torresdal.net/2008/10/24/#WebSiteStandardAction, where it goes into creating a custom action to list the existing websites and selecting one from a drop down. I suppose you can just skip the dropdown and specify the specific website to use, then reference it within your iis:WebVirtualDir section, like so:

```
<iis:WebSite Id="SelectedWebSite" Description="[WEBSITE_DESCRIPTION]">
  <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="[WEBSITE_PORT]" IP="[WEBSITE_IP]" Header="[WEBSITE_HEADER]" />
</iis:WebSite>

<iis:WebVirtualDir Id="VirtualDir" Alias="[TARGETVDIR]" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION" WebSite="SelectedWebSite">
  <iis:WebApplication Id="SimpleWebAppApp" Name="[TARGETVDIR]" WebAppPool="SWAAppPool" />
  <iis:WebDirProperties Id="WebVirtualDirProperties" Execute="yes" Script="yes" Read="yes" WindowsAuthentication="no" AnonymousAccess="yes" IIsControlledPassword="yes" />
</iis:WebVirtualDir>
```